# Getting json data (from list to detail page)

Tags: json

I've got an API (https://datatank.stad.gent/4/cultuursportvrijetijd/kunstenplan.json)
I have a list of art spot names that I got from that API displayed on a page. (actually different lists each filtered by category)
What I want is when you click on a name, you get more information about that art spot on a separate page. How do I do this?
Here's a snippet of my code that will display a list of museums.

```
    var list_museums='';
        var list_galleries='';
        var list_centers='';
        var list_offspaces='';
        var list_search='';
        var item_name='';
        var item_location='';
        var item_site='';
        var item_category='';
        var item_info='';

        for(var i=0;i<this.cultuurUtilities.length;i++)
        {
            var cultuur=this.cultuurUtilities[i];

            var museums = cultuur.categorie=="Museum";
            var galleries = cultuur.categorie=="galerie";
            var centers = cultuur.categorie=="Centrum voor beeldende kunst";
            var offspaces = cultuur.categorie=="Off-Spaces";
            console.log("cultuur for loop");

        if(museums==true){
        list_museums+='<div class="museum-item"><li class="li-museums"><img class="museum-img"></img><div class="museum-link"><a href="detailpagina.html">'+cultuur.Naam;
        list_museums+='</a></div></li></div>';
```

Comment: Try adding more information to your question to increase your chance of an answer.  I recommend reviewing [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is when you click on a name, you get more information about that art spot on a separate page

I think you mean opening a new window/tab? You can accomplish this in different ways:

1) Adding the "onclick" listener on your clickable element and write the function to be called. Inside it, you can open a new window using the "window.open" function (it opens a new window by default, so you can pass a second parameter to specify the frame where the new window/tab must be handled, because you might wanted to open the page in a new tab, not a new window. Check the [docs here](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_win_open.asp)). It returns its handle, so you can write into it, just like you do usually in your page.
For example:

```
var mywindow = window.open("path_to_follow");
// The first parameter is optional. By removing it, it will give you a blank page

mywindow.document.write("<h3>My Selected Museum</h3>");
<< bunch of other instructions >>
```

2) Using a anchor tag with "href" attribute and the selected item identifier passed as a GET parameter. For example:

```
<a target="_blank" href="path_to_follow/display_page?museum_id=dinamically_set_id">Click Here to open</a>
```

In your "display_page" (you can name it as you like) you manage to use some server-side language (like PHP, Java, etc...) to prepare a "stub" of your page, and filling with the selected museum informations, using the museum identifier we said before.

If you need further information, just comment!

Comment: I mean that for example when you're in /museums.html (the list generated from json data) and you click on a museum it goed to /details.html (already have that page) where it lists all the details about that museum!

Comment: I looked better at your code, I see that you write '<a href="detailpagina.html">'. Instead of "detailpagina.html", you must have details pages for all the museums. So you will need some parameter to identify them solely (the name I think it's ok in this case). So, you append like this: "details_" + my_json_data.museum_name + ".html". Of course, the page must exists!